# OMP - more threads than the number of processors?

Tags: c++, c, openmp

By default OpenMP directive:

`opm_get_num_threads` gives number of threads equivalent to processors/cores.

I have an 8 core machine, so it gives me 8 threads. Is that the maximum? Can I get more threads than 8, if I deliberately specify more than 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set as many threads as you want with:

```
int threads = 16;
omp_set_num_threads(threads);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e16bady3%28v=vs.80%29

But be sure you are aware of the drawbacks of using more threads than there are logical cores in the system.

Comment: Care to share what the drawbacks actually are rather than just vaguely alluding to them?

Comment: @LexiR There's overhead when dealing with threads: scheduling, context switches, cache contention, etc... It's not to say that it's never better to use more threads than logical cores. But it's helpful to know what can happen if it's misused.

Comment: Why fix the number of threads in code? How about the good old environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`?

Comment: @HristoIliev That's up to the OP. I prefer not to touch environment varibles - especially if different apps have different # of optimal threads.

Comment: Is there a way to get the number of Physical Cores (Namely without SMT / HyperThreading)?

Comment: @Royi It can be done, but it's not trivial. In Windows you'll have to walk the processor topology API. In Linux, you'll need to parse `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: Is this useful in the event that you have some heterogeneous process, so over threading acts like a thread pool and would assign threads to the first available core(s).  For a triangular decreasing set of process workloads this might optimally scheduled the cores.